# Shuffling list of competitors, each month different competitor

Tags: c#, random, shuffle

for my friends sportscompetition, each player has to play 1 game a month against an other player. Now if i have a list of 20 players or so its not that hard to randomize the first month so i have 10 matches.

All the months after that though i'm not sure how to get the randomizer working so they won't be matched against a player they have played against.

Right now i made an sql database with Players(Name, (int)Id, Email) , Matches(Id, Player1ID, Player2ID)

I'm thinking for a randomize of the list and checking if each match doesn't contain 2 id's from a match in the database. And if 1 match does, redo the entire randomize of that month.

But i'm not sure if thats the best way.

This is what i have so far, i have yet to test it after i add some 'leden' and 'matches' to my database.

```
    private void MaakMatchen(Maand maand)
    {
        List<Lid> leden = new List<Lid>();
        var dbManager = new Manager();
        using (var conGildenhof = dbManager.GetConnection())
        {
            using (var comLeden = conGildenhof.CreateCommand())
            {
                comLeden.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
                comLeden.CommandText = "select * from dbo.Leden";
                conGildenhof.Open();
                using (var alleleden = comLeden.ExecuteReader())
                {
                    Int32 voornaamPos = alleleden.GetOrdinal("Voornaam");
                    Int32 familienaamPos = alleleden.GetOrdinal("Familienaam");
                    Int32 LidNummerPos = alleleden.GetOrdinal("LidNummer");

                    while (alleleden.Read())
                    {
                        leden.Add(new Classes.Lid(alleleden.GetString(voornaamPos), alleleden.GetString(familienaamPos), alleleden.GetInt32(LidNummerPos)));
                    }
                    leden = Randomize(leden);
                }
            }

            using (var comInsert = conGildenhof.CreateCommand())
            {
                comInsert.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
                comInsert.CommandText = "Insert into dbo.Matches (Lid1Id, Lid2Id, Maand) values (@lid1, @lid2, @maand)";

                var parLid1 = comInsert.CreateParameter();
                parLid1.ParameterName = "@lid1";
                comInsert.Parameters.Add(parLid1);

                var parLid2 = comInsert.CreateParameter();
                parLid2.ParameterName = "@lid2";
                comInsert.Parameters.Add(parLid2);

                var parMaand = comInsert.CreateParameter();
                parMaand.ParameterName = "@maand";
                comInsert.Parameters.Add(parMaand);


                int lengte = leden.Count();
                for (int i = 0; i < lengte; i = i + 2)
                {
                    parLid1.Value = leden[i].LidNummer;
                    parLid2.Value = leden[i + 1].LidNummer;
                    parMaand.Value = (int)maand;

                    comInsert.ExecuteNonQuery();
                }
            }
        }
    }

    private List<Lid> Randomize(List<Lid> leden)
    {
        for (int i=0;i<100;i++)
        {
            leden = Shuffle(leden);
        }
        int temp = CheckUp(leden);
        while (temp != 100)
        {
            leden = Shuffle(leden, temp);
            temp = CheckUp(leden);
        }
        return leden;
    }

    private List<Lid> Shuffle(List<Lid> leden)
    {
        Random rnd = new Random();
        int a = rnd.Next(1, leden.Count() + 1);
        int b = rnd.Next(1, leden.Count() + 1);

        var temp = new Lid();
        temp = leden[a];
        leden[a] = leden[b];
        leden[b] = temp;

        return leden;
    }

    private List<Lid> Shuffle(List<Lid> leden, int id)
    {
        Random rnd = new Random();
        int a = rnd.Next(1, leden.Count() + 1);
        int b = id;

        var temp = new Lid();
        temp = leden[a];
        leden[a] = leden[b];
        leden[b] = temp;

        return leden;
    }

    private int CheckUp(List<Lid> leden)
    {
        int lengte = leden.Count();
        List<Matches> matches = new List<Matches>();
        var dbManager = new Manager();
        using (var conGildenhof = dbManager.GetConnection())
        {
            using (var comMatches = conGildenhof.CreateCommand())
            {
                comMatches.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
                comMatches.CommandText = "select * from dbo.Matches";
                conGildenhof.Open();
                using (var allematches = comMatches.ExecuteReader())
                {
                    Int32 lid1Pos = allematches.GetOrdinal("Lid1Id");
                    Int32 lid2Pos = allematches.GetOrdinal("Lid2Id");
                    Int32 maandPos = allematches.GetOrdinal("Maand");

                    while (allematches.Read())
                    {
                        matches.Add(new Classes.Matches(allematches.GetInt32(lid1Pos), allematches.GetInt32(lid2Pos), (Maand)allematches.GetInt32(maandPos)));
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        for (int i=0;i<lengte;i=i+2)
        {
            foreach (Matches match in matches)
            {
                if (leden[i].LidNummer == match.Lid1Id)
                {
                    if (leden[i + 1].LidNummer == match.Lid2Id)
                        return leden[i].LidNummer;
                }
                if (leden[i].LidNummer == match.Lid2Id)
                {
                    if (leden[i + 1].LidNummer == match.Lid1Id)
                        return leden[i].LidNummer;
                }
            }
        }
        return 100;
    }

    private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        var maand = new int();
        int.TryParse(TextBoxMaand.Text, out maand);
        if (maand == 0)
            TextBoxMaand.Text = "GETAL!";
        else
        {
            MaakMatchen((Maand)maand);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Do the matches really need to be random, or do you just want every possible combination of matches?

Comment: I'm guessing you need to make a round robin schedule. Maybe a random list of 20, matching 0 with 10, 1 with 11 and so on till you get to 9-19. Then you just switch possitions in the list making the last item the first one and shifting each item one possition up. Rinse and repeat untill you have your full schedule done.

Answer (score 0):

I would shuffle the players first and create the matches in a second iteration

```
List<Player> players = GetPlayers();
Random _rnd = new Random();
// shuffle players
players = players.OrderBy(_ => _rnd.Next()).ToList();
// create matches
var matches = players.Take(players.Count / 2).Zip(players.Skip(players.Count / 2), (p1, p2) => new Match(p1,p2));
```

https://dotnetfiddle.net/sGxbx4

Comment: The matches have to be random, and if player 1 and 2 had to go against eachother in januari perhaps, then in all the other months they can't be matched against eachother.

Comment: @Dylan, you should edit your question to include your code, and explain what else it needs to do.

Comment: yeah, i edited it, i realized now i should have put my code in english as well